# Reversi or Backgammon for Terminal?

Tags: gaming

How can I install any shell/console implementations of either Reversi (Othello) or Backgammon games?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Check the page [ask] and the page about what is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question adding the version of the system and the problem you find... If there will be someone that will think useful your questions or answers you will receive [upvotes](http://superuser.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: If you will exit from the scope of the site your question will be closed or transferred. Nothing personal :-) Today is the [International_Women's_Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Women's_Day), you were _well educated_, it is your first post and your nick is a name of a [saint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zita): this granted you an answer (an exception) but it will not protect your question to be closed by others :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a fast google search it comes out that

- You can find a version of [reversi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reversi) on the site of the Haskell community's central package archive of open source software that you have to download and compile.
- [Backgammon](http://www.junauza.com/2014/07/games-you-can-play-from-your-linux-terminal.html) instead can be found as a part of the [bsdgames](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games), that you can install e.g. with

  `sudo apt-get install bsdgames`.